# How to add json (send/consume) validation against schema middleware in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, json, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to add json validation against json schema in MassTransit send/consume pipeline.
I can't find any related docs.
I'm using RabbitMq transport.
I have no problems with the validation realisation.
How to correctly add middleware?

Answer (score 0):

The message isn't serialized until it's being written to the transport, so even though you *could* create middleware on the publish or send pipeline, it wouldn't be the actual JSON put into the message body.

There are plenty of [examples](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) of building MassTransit middleware, but I'm not sure what you want is going to actually be useful. You could always build it into the JSON serializer by creating your own custom version of the [JsonMessageSerializer](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Serialization/JsonMessageSerializer.cs).

Comment: thanks for you answer!
I'll make a custom serializer.